# Typings ambient install not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsd

I am trying to install some ambient typings, but it is no longer working on my machine. I recently upgraded node so not sure if this caused it. It seems to not be looking in the dt location anymore.

This is the error I get:

```
~/w/r/c/src (master ⚡☡) typings search moment-timezone
Viewing 1 of 1

NAME            SOURCE HOMEPAGE                      DESCRIPTION VERSIONS UPDATED
moment-timezone dt     http://momentjs.com/timezone/             1        2016-03-29T22:03:48.000Z

~/w/r/c/src (master ⚡☡) typings i moment-timezone --ambient
typings ERR! message Unable to find "moment-timezone" ("npm") in the registry. Did you want to try searching another source? Also, if you want contribute these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/moment-timezone/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200

typings ERR! cwd /Users/pete/work/ruuby/calendar-sync/src
typings ERR! system Darwin 15.3.0
typings ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/typings" "i" "moment-timezone" "--ambient"
typings ERR! node -v v6.1.0
typings ERR! typings -v 1.0.3

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

Comment: I just noticed from looking at the help for `typings install` --ambient is no longer supported. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is here: https://github.com/typings/typings/releases/tag/v1.0.0

TLDR: `--ambient` has changed to `--global`

**UPDATE From comment below**

You need to specify the repository too e.g.:

```
typings install dt~moment-timezone --global
```

Comment: It seems that you also need to specify the repository explicitly too (default is npm):

`typings install dt~moment-timezome --global`

Comment: @StewartFrancis tanks for saving the day !

Comment: Great! We have a typo "moment-timezome" but worked like a charm. Thanks!